# Same hashing + encryption in different platforms generating unidentical values

Tags: java, android, encryption, hash

I am writing some web-services for a social networking website. These web-services would be utilized by android for making android-app. As the person who designed the website is no longer under contact, I looked at the whole website code which was written in java with spring framework. I am writing web services in php.

Now, when I tried to send a post request to a php page that would confirm if the given username & pass combination is correct or not and then return a session id. But i'm not being able to get the correct hashing method to get correct hash value that is saved in the database.
Because of this, everytime, I am getting rejected by the php code.

The encryption that I found on the website code is as follows:

```
public static final synchronized String encrypt(String plaintext, String algorithm, String encoding) throws Exception
{
  MessageDigest msgDigest = null;
  String hashValue = null;
  try
  {
    msgDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    msgDigest.update(plaintext.getBytes(encoding));
    byte rawByte[] = msgDigest.digest();
    hashValue = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(rawByte);

  }
  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
  {
    System.out.println("No Such Algorithm Exists");
  }
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
  {
    System.out.println("The Encoding Is Not Supported");
  }
  return hashValue;
}
```

For example, if i am giving password as monkey123 as password, it is giving hash value encoded in base 64 as:  hge2WiM7vlaTTS1qU404+Q==

Now, after struggling to do the same in php for hours, I realised I could do the above procedure in android itself. So, I wrote the following code:

```
MessageDigest pwdDigest=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
pwdDigest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-16"));
byte rawbyte[]=pwdDigest.digest();
String passwordHash=Base64.encodeToString(rawbyte,Base64.DEFAULT);


URL url = new URL(loginURL);

HttpURLConnection Connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
Connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

Connection.setDoOutput(true);

//set the request to POST and send

Connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(Connection.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes("username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8"));
out.writeBytes("&password="+URLEncoder.encode(passwordHash,"UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();
if(Connection.getResponseCode()==200){
  String data="Connected";            
  return data;
} else 
  return Connection.getResponseCode()+": "+Connection.getResponseMessage();
```

I expected this would be successful because in both the cases, I am doing same process to encrypt the password, but amazingly, this is not giving the hash value as: 
  `hge2WiM7vlaTTS1qU404+Q==` but it's giving : `nZlvVe7GSS2Zso1dOwJrIA==`

I am really struggling to find out a reason why these two are not the same. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is the encoding you are using in the website code ?

Comment: The encryption function is called as: 
   `public String getEncryptPassword() {
  try {
   return MyPasswordEncrypt.encrypt(getPassword(), "MD5", "UTF-16");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return encryptPassword;
  }
 }`

Comment: After using UTF-16, you send it across as UTF-8 encoded.That could be the possible problem.

Comment: I tried changing the android posting code to UTF-16 too,that isnt helping either..

Comment: Are you doing the encoding again for the website code as well, as is in the android app.

Comment: I'd concur with Ric, you're encoding the password, then passing to the web page by encoding again in UTF-8. That second encoding is likely the problem. You've already base 64 encoded it; you don't need to modify it again. And you're using SSL to send that response, right?

Comment: Ric, no I guess not.. and I dont have a handle to the website code.. that is the problem to be honest. Isnt it like: 
In website code: 
 password-> utf-16 encoded pwd-> md5 hash-> base 64 encoded hash.
In android:
 pwd->utf-16 encoded pwd-> md5 hash -> base 64 encoded hash ( sending it as utf-8 encoded).. You think this is the problem? 

@user1676075 -- No, until now, no ssl is there, it will be in near  future I guess.
 For now my url:
http://108.168.240.115/doodlemobileserver/login.php

Comment: Well, turns out, 
 out.writeBytes("&password="+URLEncoder.encode(passwordHash,"UTF-8")); and
 out.writeBytes("&password="+passwordHash); 
both do same thing.. so no problem in that either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't expect MD5 to differ between platforms. It's stable and well documented and part of the core libraries. If this were broken in some Android version, nothing would work on that phone.

The re-encoding into UTF-8 is harmless, because all Base64 characters fit into the lower ASCII range. Three characters of the base64 alphabet require URL encoding, but you would have seen the %-escapes if something went wrong there.

Base64 is less stable ground (lots and lots of different implementations, no single canonical one), but it's not exactly rocket science either. Again, I don't expect a faulty implementation to really make it out into the wild, but the Base64 step may be where the difference arises.

Personally, I suspect the error is introduced during the `password.getBytes("UTF-16")` call. A quick way to verify this hunch is to inspect the resulting byte array in a debugger on both platforms. **According to [`java.lang.Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), the "UTF-16" encoding will use big endian byte order, whereas your PHP code may be defaulting to little endian because it's running on x86 and no byte order mark is present** (I don't know PHP well enough to tell if this behaviour is well defined). Try modifying the Java code to use `password.getBytes("UTF-16LE")` and see if that makes a difference.

*Side note: MD5 is no longer considered secure for hashing passwords; you'll want to use something like scrypt or PBKDF2 with plenty of rounds and a random salt, but that's a topic unto itself.*

Comment: Barend, I totally agree with you. In fact I had already checked what output password.getBytes("UTF-16") would give on both cases and it is not the same. So, I can confirm that its not base64, or md5 that is giving the problem. It is UTF-16.

In android, password.getBytes("UTF-16") gives array values as: 
-1 -2 49 0 49 0 52 0 49 0 52 0 50 0 49 0 97 0 98 0 99 0

While in java, it gives array values as: 
 -2 -1 0 49 0 49 0 52 0 49 0 52 0 50 0 49 0 97 0 98 0 99

So, it seems that it is the problem.. Any views on that?

Comment: Barend, I have solved the problem.. As you can see the values of arrays are just adjacently misplaced, I just swapped these values so that it generated a correct hash..and so it has. Thank you for your help.:)